# GitHub Restriction Policy

Tags: github

I am trying to restrict PR merging to only specific users say 2, I created a workflow that will check for the collaborator doing the merge on the restricted branch e.g. Master branch using the below script but then when one of the authorised  merger is trying to merge it is requiring that the second merger must also do the merge before it can work. How do i specify that if only one of the specified merger make the merge request it should be successful

```
name: actions_on_master_branch
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - reopened
    branches:    
      - 'master'

jobs:
  job1:
    name: check_adminA
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NAME_ADMIN: ramseyolu
    steps:
      - name: st1
        if: ${{ github.actor != env.NAME_ADMIN }}
        run: exit 1
      - name: st2
        if: ${{ github.actor == env.NAME_ADMIN }}
        run: echo "ok"
  job2:
    name: check_adminB
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      NAME_ADMIN: stephcurl
    steps:
      - name: st1
        if: ${{ github.actor != env.NAME_ADMIN }}
        run: exit 1
      - name: st2
        if: ${{ github.actor == env.NAME_ADMIN }}
        run: echo "ok"
```